# How to handle default dropdown values using jquery ajax in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Based on selection of first dropdown i am binding another drop down values based on first dropdownid value.My question is i given default first dropdown value as "select" but there is no id value for that in second dropdown to get the values.if user selectes "select" in frist dropdown i need to load all values in second dropdown.please tell me how to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

If you given default first dropdown value as "select" means, at that time disable the second drop down value. If `'country'` value equal to `'select'` means, at that time disable the `'state drop down'`.When we click that country 'select' at that time also call that disable drop down function.

For example HTML view page, country drop down displayed. From that you will get country ID.

```
 $countryID=> From your MVC code you have pass default country ID (default ID)
 $countrySelected=$this->getCountryFromName(trim($countryID']));

if ($countrySelected!= ''){ 
    $sVal=$this->getStateList($countrySelected);                            
    $newStateList=array('0'=>'State');                           
    $newStateList+=$this->formatDropdownArray($sVal,'STATE_ID','NAME');
    $stateSelected='State';
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('STATE_IDD',$stateSelected,$newStateList,array('tabindex'=>9));                
}else{
    $stateSelected=$defaultState;
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('STATE_IDD',$stateSelected,$stateList,array('tabindex'=>9));               
}
```

Comment: if user selects the default value in first dropdown then i need to load all values in second dropdown .

Comment: no. Not like that. In default state drop down also contains, default state list.You just disable that dropdown list using user interface. Not disable the functionality. So you dont want to load all values again.When user click the country except default value, then you will pass that ajax/load all values in that state drop down